# Looking to extract COUNTRY and CITY along with their count from Addresses

Tags: python, api, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

Looking for a solution that can help me in extracting CITY, COUNTRY and COUNT. Used below code but not able to fetch. Since I am new to this can someone help,

```
import spacy
import wikipedia
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

gpe = []  # countries, cities, states

doc = nlp(open("C:/Users/johns//Desktop/NewFolder/address1.txt").read())

for ent in doc.ents:
    if ent.label_ == 'GPE':
        gpe.append(ent.text)

cities = []
countries = []

import wikipedia
for text in gpe:
    summary = str(wikipedia.summary(text))
    if 'city' in summary:
        cities.append(text)
        #print(cities)
    elif 'country' in summary:
        countries.append(text)
        #print(countries)
    print(countries, cities)
```

Data is in below format:

```
60 MOHI EL DIN ABHU EZZ STREET GIZA Egypt 
KEBHANA BANK FORMER KOREA EXCHANGEB FOREIGN OPERATIONS DEPARTMENT 101 2 KA ULCHI RD CHUNG KU
RamEnclave 16-16/1 Navi Road New Delhi India 1/22/14 SS Mart Gaazi Road Islamabad Pakistan
KEBHANA BANK FORMER KOREA EXCHANGEB OPERATIONS DEPT 101 2 KA ULCHI RD CHUNG KU
7Hills appt Narsingi Hyderabad India
```

Answer (score 0):

spaCy is trained on complete sentences, like found in newspapers, which is not similar to your data. Also while it has some named entity tags that correspond to locations, it doesn't differentiate between cities and countries, for example. Your approach to converting GPEs to cities and countries is interesting but seems unlikely to work.

You should look at using software specifically for address extraction. You should be able to include it in a spaCy pipeline usefully, and if you have annotated data you can train a model in spaCy, but to get started you should probably look at address-specific packages.